# powershell import csv and filter on names to run enable-remotemailbox and update attributes

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server

i am at my wits end with trying to get this script to work so far, if I run the script without filtering on users, it works based on the searchbase filtering on the OU,  but soon as I try to filter on the users as well, it is throwing errors such as

> "The term '​​' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
> script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
> if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
> At C:\Users\user\Desktop\UserProvisioning and licence v2.ps1:22
> char:27"

and

> "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
> C:\Users\user\Desktop\UserProvisioning and licence v2.ps1:23 char:1
>
> - Enable-RemoteMailbox -Identity $users.SamAccountName -RemoteRoutingAd ."

I appreciate if someone could please have a look at my code and tell me what is going wrong here?

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.SnapIn

$accountNamesToInclude = @("Dev01","Dev02")

Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase 'OU=orgunit1,DC=ad,DC=domain,DC=com' | Export-Csv E:\Scripts\ProvisionUsers.csv

$Names = @()
$UPNS = @()
$Licence = "Licence-M365-E5"
$accountNamesToInclude = @('Dev01','Dev02')

# Comment this out if you want to include all users from the csv
($users = Import-Csv E:\Scripts\ProvisionUsers.csv | Where-Object { $accountNamesToInclude -contains $_.Name })
# Uncomment this if you want to include all users from the csv
# $users = Import-Csv E:\Scripts\ProvisionUsers.csv

foreach ($user in $users){​​
Enable-RemoteMailbox -Identity $users.SamAccountName -RemoteRoutingAddress((($_.UserPrincipalName.split("@")[0])) +"@domain.mail.onmicrosoft.com") -PrimarySmtpAddress((($_.UserPrincipalName.split("@")[0])) +"@domain.com"); 
}
foreach ($user in $users){
Get-ADUser -Identity $users.SamAccountName | Set-ADObject -Replace @{extensionAttribute8=$Licence} 
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$user.samaccountname`, you're still referencing the entirety of the array with `$users.sama..`. So change it to `$user` without the *s*.

Comment: Thanks Abraham,  I tried that before and wasn't successful but one more step in the right direction.  Cheers.

Comment: Why did you change it? Lol that's the correct way to do it(: getting any errors now?

Comment: Lol trial and error,  still the same error unfortunately...
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\users\Desktop\UserProvisioning and licence v2.ps1:28 char:1
+ Enable-RemoteMailbox -Identity $user.SamAccountName -RemoteRoutingAdd

Comment: Change the `$_` to the corresponding variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try now with this code. In addition to what [Abraham commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67497074/powershell-import-csv-and-filter-on-names-to-run-enable-remotemailbox-and-update#comment119302639_67497074) your other error was using `$_` in a `foreach` loop which would return `$null` and then trying to use the `split` method over a null value.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.SnapIn
$Licence = "Licence-M365-E5"
$accountNamesToInclude = @('Dev01','Dev02')

Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase 'OU=orgunit1,DC=ad,DC=domain,DC=com' |
Export-Csv E:\Scripts\ProvisionUsers.csv

$Names = @()
$UPNS = @()

$users = Import-Csv E:\Scripts\ProvisionUsers.csv | Where-Object {
    $accountNamesToInclude -contains $_.Name
}

foreach ($user in $users)
{​​
    $name = $user.UserPrincipalName.split("@")[0]
    
    $hash = @{
        Identity = $user.DistinguishedName
        RemoteRoutingAddress = "$name@domain.mail.onmicrosoft.com"
        PrimarySmtpAddress = "$name@domain.com"
    }
    Enable-RemoteMailbox @hash
    Set-ADObject $user.DistinguishedName -Replace @{extensionAttribute8=$Licence}
}
```

Comment: Hi Santiago,  thank you very much for that response and solution.  So they mailbox provisioning works however the extensionAttribute is not...
Set-ADObject : Cannot find an object with identity: 'Dev01' under: 'DC=ad,DC=domain,DC=com'
Weird one as the remotemailbox had no issues in working for these users. 

Thanks

Comment: Hi Santiago,  Thanks again,  I worked it out, Just needed to update the line to 
Set-ADObject $user.DistinguishedName -Replace @{extensionAttribute8=$Licence}

As the Set-ADObject didnt work with the SamAccountName and needed the DistinguishedName.

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @speed_racer glad to help, yes I should've mentioned that, it's always a best practice when update objects on `AD` to use `distinguishedName`, `objectGUID` or `SID`.